# Question about MySQL ORDER BY

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `posts` where I have two fields called `timestamp_added` and `timestamp_edited`.

I want to order by the latest added or edited posts descending.

`ORDER BY p.timestamp_added DESC, p.timestamp_edited DESC`, does not give me what I need.

I would love something like:

```
ORDER BY IF p.timestamp_edited > 0 THEN p.timestamp_edited DESC ELSE p.timestamp_added DESC
```

How do I do this? I have tried to google this, but I have trouble finding what I need.

Comment: Have you tried `ORDER BY p.timestamp_edited DESC, p.timestamp_added DESC`?

Comment: You simply update timestamp_edited to be equal to timestamp_added once you create the entry and you order by timestamp_edited. That way you don't need complex SQL that will hog down the performance and you can still see when the entry was created and last updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the timestamp_edited NULL when not set?

In that case you could do:

```
ORDER BY IFNULL(p.timestamp_edited, p.timestamp_added) DESC
```

If it's 0 when not set:

```
ORDER BY IF(p.timestamp_edited > 0, p.timestamp_edited, p.timestamp_added) DESC
```

Comment: He doesn't explicitly say it's 0, that's the comparison he's trying and it's obviously not working. In case it IS null, however, this is how he can do it.

Comment: Yes I deleted my comment as for all we know it could be `NULL` +1

Comment: Thanks guys!

It really helped me out! 


The timestamp_edited is 0 when not set.

I used brains solution...

Answer (score 1):

Your version was close. This should do what you need and is standard SQL

```
ORDER BY 
   CASE WHEN p.timestamp_edited > 0 
        THEN p.timestamp_edited 
        ELSE p.timestamp_added 
   END DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

AS N.B. suggested, your `timestamp_edited` should be same as `timestamp_added` at the time of creation and then simply use `ORDER BY timestamp_edited DESC`

Answer (score 0):

In case you store `p.timestamp_edited` as 00-00-00T00:00:00 by default You could try `ORDER BY GREATEST(p.timestamp_edited, p.timestamp_added) DESC`

**Update**
This Case also handles null and I checked it on a database and works perfectly

`ORDER BY GREATEST(p.timestamp_added, IFNULL(p.timestamp_edited, 0)) DESC`